# how to change month in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I need below values to be changed in my script every month. I am using ksh shell in HP-UX environment. There are 4 things to be changed each month i.e., current month (I got it), previous month,whatever month is found in script should be incremented by next month (APR to MAY),the values 2016-05 and 2016-06 should take next month values 2016-06 and 2016-07. Please let me know the commands and possible ways to do it.

Note: here previous month and partition names are same but they are not always same.

My script is

```
curmon=$(echo `date +'%b'`|tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')

This month is ${curmon}.

Previous month is ${premon}.

alter table test add PARTITION test_APR01
VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-05-22 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
tablespace abc;

alter table test add PARTITION test_APR02
VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-05-25 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
tablespace abc;

alter table test add PARTITION test_APR03
VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
tablespace abc;
```

I should get my output like this.

```
This month is JAN.

Previous month is DEC.

alter table test add PARTITION test_MAY01
VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-06-22 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
tablespace abc;

alter table test add PARTITION test_MAY02
VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-06-25 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
tablespace abc;

alter table test add PARTITION test_MAY03
VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2016-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
tablespace abc;
```

Comment: what is the relation with JAN and 2016-07 ??  6 months later?  Should the year change when current month becomes JUL?

Comment: Yes 6 months later.. This script is edited on 27th of every month. So the above script is done on 27th Dec. So it is test_MAY.

Comment: When it is changed this month 27th i.e., 27th Jan 2016, it should be test_JUN and the partition values should be 2016-07 and 2016-08 respectively.

Comment: Is this Oracle? There are plenty of date functions there. I'd recommend you do the date math in your SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a date other than `now` to `date` with the `--date` option. E.g.:

```
date --date "Last month" +%b
```

Will return (as of today) `dec`.

See [info docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats) for more information.

Regarding the other values, it's not quite clear to me what you mean. Should it be dependent on whatever is in the script from before? It sounds to me like you have a base value - I think you should be able to work that out with the same mechanism. For example:

```
date --date "2016-06-22 +1 month" +%F
2016-07-22
```

Comment: I am sorry if I have created any confusion. Yes the new values are dependant on old values. The command above given is not working.    $ date --date "Last month" +%b
date: illegal option -- -
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
       date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
       date [-a [-]sss.fff]

Comment: date --date "2016-06-22 +1 month" +%F
date: illegal option -- -
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
       date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
       date [-a [-]sss.fff]

Comment: OK sorry, my answer is regarding GNU date. Bad assumption. In that case I'm afraid I can't help. In regards to the values from the script, I think you should find a way to store that "base" date or "last" date outside of the script, instead of "overwriting" the script each time, if that makes any sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
YEST=$(echo $(date +%s) - 60*60*24 | bc);python -c "import datetime;print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int($YEST)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))"
```

result.

> 2016-01-06 15:52:03

1st. change "YEST"

2st. change to the desired format 
 **"strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"**

Other language(php or perl) can do it too

Comment: @Jae, I cannot find python and strftime in my ksh.                                                            $ YEST=$(echo $(date +%s) - 60*60*24 | bc);python -c "import datetime;print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int($YEST)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))"
/usr/bin/ksh: python:  not found

Comment: I used below expression to get next 6 months value. But it works only till Dec. Once the year changes, the code doesn't work. Please help on this.     m=`date +%m`
m=$(($m + 6))                                                                                                 Y=`date +%Y`                                                                                               output=echo $Y-0$m

Comment: The above output is fine till Jun i.e., 6+6 but once July comes, month will be 07 and adding 6 would be 13. My command doesn't satisfies my logic in the script. If the %m is 07 then i should get something like 2017-01 as output. Please suggest on this.

Comment: look at this `cur=$(date +%m)` `next6=$(printf %02d $(echo $(($cur+6))%12 | bc))`

Comment: Thank you Baek. I got month output correct, how can I get year also as 2017 and request you to explain me what does above command do.             cur=08                                                                                                              next6=$(printf %02d $(echo $(($cur+6))%12 | bc))                                        output I got is 02.

Comment: How about this? `next6_y=$(echo $(($cur+6))/12 + $(date +%Y) | bc)`

Comment: Many many thanks Baek. I got desired output. :)                                                  Could you please explain me the commands.

Comment: You are welcome! look at [this](https://gist.github.com/jybaek/a5275a0b29a5534aa9c3)